# Pricing Details for Azure Kubernetes Service and Service Fabric on free tier

Tags: azure, azure-free-services

I was able to sign up for a free Azure for Students account, which has the same limits as with the Azure free tier. On the "Free Service" service, this is written:

[image: Service Fabric "Free" image]

As well as this:

[image: AKS "Free" image]

While I understand that "you are only charged for the computer, storage, networking, etc. resources you use" (from Microsoft's website), what can we logically do with AKS and Service Fabric in the free tier? For example, with Virtual Machines, you can Linux and Windows B1S VMs for 1500 hours every month. This means I can provision B1S VMs, one Linux and one Windows, and leave them running for up to 1500 hours per month.

To summarize, can we provision any AKS cluster (with some amount of worker nodes), or a Service Fabric cluster without incurring any charges (a logical way to use these services) in a similar way to how I can create VMs and use them within these limits for free? And if not, is there any other alternative that is free?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AKS cluster itself is free, but you cant use b1s nodes for the system node pool (they are too small):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quotas-skus-regions#restricted-vm-sizes

so the answer would be no.

EDIT: sorry, forgot about the Service Fabric part of the question. I dont see why that wouldn't work apart from the fact that it would be next to impossible to actually deploy anything useful on top of b1s vm that's running all of the SF binaries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity

Comment: How about for service fabric?